# Second-order correction in Quantum-Confined Stark effect

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, perturbation-theory

In the wikipedia article, there is a second-order correction in the [Quantum-Confined Stark Effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum-confined_Stark_effect). I could not understand how it was solved. I did not understand the meaning of 2(0) and 1(0) and how I could get $m$.

[image]